# How to call invoke when use Func<string, bool>

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

In the function `Test(Func<string,bool> f)`, how to call f.invoke()? I received the error
Delegate 'Func' does not take '0' arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate `Func<string, bool>` is a delegate that takes a string as an argument and returns bool.  To invoke it, you need to supply a string.

e.g., either should work

```
f("foo");
f.Invoke("foo");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bool b = f(someString);
```

or:

```
bool b = f.Invoke(someString);
```

Comment: I need to call like f.invoke(soemthing), how to get the something from parameter?