# How to make the following code snippet work and How to pass the parameter to invoke?

Tags: c#, .net

using System;

f.involk() failed since it needs a string parameter, how to correct the code?

```
    namespace LamdaTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Test(Func<string,bool> f)
            {
                **f.Invoke();**
            }

            static bool GetItem(string s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("getItem");
                if (s == "123") return true;
                else return false; 
            }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Test((string s)=> GetItem("123"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I answered your similar [prior question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190859/how-to-call-invoke-when-use-funcstring-bool/4190873#4190873).  If you need to follow-up, please edit that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
**f.Invoke();**
```

with:

```
f(null);
```

However, if you are not using the `string` argument, you should instead use the delegate type `Func<bool>` or `Action`.

Comment: can you explain further? It is working, but a little counterintuitive

Comment: It's not counterintuitive.  Here: `Test((string s)=> GetItem("123"));` you created a delegate that accepts a `string` parameter and then **does absolutely nothing with it**.  So it **does not matter** what you pass in to the delegate.  You could call `f("french toast");` and get the same result as `f(null);`.  If you instead said `Test((string s)=> GetItem(s));` then `f("123");` would return true and anything else would return false.

Comment: Need to combine your answer and ace's answer to get the complete solution

Comment: Ace's answer is one possible solution to your problem... the example is a bit vague; there are many ways you could correct it.

Comment: I look if there is a solution without using additional parameter like ace's solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Test(Func<string, bool> f, string s)
        {
            f.Invoke(s);
        }

        static bool GetItem(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("getItem");
            if (s == "123") return true;
            else return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test(GetItem, "Test String");


        }
```

Comment: this is straight forward solution, thanks. but cdhowie's one is better I think

Comment: I thought in your question you want a way to pass a string and call your delegate, if you don't care about passing the string then Action is a better option.

Comment: I need a way to pass the string. so I think I need to call

Comment: Test( (string s)=>GetItem(s), "Test String"). I cannot pass the GetItem directly to Test

Comment: I don't really understand, you can pass the string as the second argument in my example above

Comment: @ace, I want to know if there is a solution without the second parameter passing.

Comment: will you always have the same string s being passed to GetItem(string s)? or will it be different?